# Flot chat rendering probleme when importing mongodb data

Tags: mongodb, charts, flot, mongoimport, mongoexport

I have a web application that shows data in charts format using the flot chart plugin, the data is retrived from a mongoDB database.
I deployed the web aplication in an other computer, and when I exported the database using mongoexport and import it in the new computer using mongoimport, the flot chart dont render the data properly ([image](https://postimg.org/image/z2dxy9n1v/)), but the chart in my computer is showing good ([image](https://postimg.org/image/4xphcwpoj/)).

I also used mongodump and mongorestor, but in vain. and when I put the address of my computer as the adress of the mongoDB in the new computer,it works fine.

Comment: It looks like the data is not ordered by time in the bad chart (so the chart sometimes goes back). Do you order the data manually?

Comment: I do not order the data manually, I use a PHP code to oreder the data from the database. In fact, that same code is used in the new computer, but still have the same problem. Could it be a problem due to the mongo version? because I do not have the same version in both computers.